# redirect all pages to single page in php no htaccess

Tags: php

I have a form to complete the profile of the users I want that if some input its not filled the user can not leave the current page for example: even if he clicks on a menu which is redirected on the current page

Comment: i want to know how to do that ?

Comment: What did you feel?

Comment: _i want to know how to do that ?...._ What you need is the code. But we don't write code for you :) Show us your best attempt and describe what is not working there. Post your code

Comment: I know I thought of a if isset but I don't know where or started

Comment: Start by researching about "user input validation". Without seeing any line of your code  nobody is gonna be able to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that in html by typing 'required="true"' in the input tag but it can be change in anytime by the user so i recommended to use a php filter instead.
by using `is_empty()` to check if it empty or not 
, or make a filter using `filter_var($var,filter_type)` 
you wanna visit [click here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-filter_var-function/) to know more about the filter

and now after we checked about empty fields and filter it , 
we can add the info to database , write it ......,

and in the end you wanna redirect the user to another page using `header("location:index.php");`